# How do I stop my hamburger menu automatically opening?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the hamburger menu opens automatically when its in mobile view and then once I close the hamburger menu and change from mobile to normal view it then responds by not opening auto. As soon as I refresh the page though it goes back to auto open.
Please help thanks in advance :)

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links nav-active">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger toggle">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

css

@media screen and (max-width:768px){

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;/*hides the nav)*/
}

.nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color:#5D4954;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%); /*this pops the nav off to the side)*/
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.nav-links li{
    opacity: 1; /* opacity 0 hides nav links opacity1 reveals nav links*/
}
.burger{
    display: block;
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    display: flex;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
        
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px); 
    }
}

.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}
.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}
```

}

Javascript

```
const navSlide = () =>  {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger'); //just selects one being the burger menu
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li'); // selects all nav-link li's
}
```

```
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //animate links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = '';
        } else{
            link.style.animation = 'navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + .5}s';
        }
        
    });

    //burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You open/close your nav by toggling the class 'nav-active', right? So if you start in mobile view, the nav opens, then you close it by toggling that class. Your 'nav-active"-class is gone now, and it does not magically reappear when you change your viewport. That's why your menu stays hidden when you go back to "normal" view.

"Normal view" by the way is mobile, since mobile views started overtaking desktop views back in 2016. In March 2021 Google even replaced "mobile first" ranking with "mobile ONLY".

If you want your menu to auto-open on every page load regardless of the viewport - all is good!

If you want your menu to be always open on desktop view, you have to add that

```
"transform: translateX(0%);
display: flex;
```

from your 'nav-active'-class into your 'nav-links'-styles (for desktop view only of course).